# Bubble Sorting an Array of random values of 1-100

Tags: java, random, bubble-sort

This was assignment 1.

Now I have to create the same thing but use a random array of 1-100 values and i have no clue how implement that into what i already have.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
    int i;



    int[] array = {9,1,5,8,7,2,1,5,5,6,8,15,3,9,19,18,88,10,1,100,4,8};
    System.out.println("Values Before the sort:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        System.out.print(array[i] + "  ");
    System.out.println();
    bubble_srt(array, array.length);
    System.out.print("Values after the sort:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        System.out.print(array[i] + "  ");
    System.out.println();



}

public static void bubble_srt(int a[], int n) {
    int i, j, t = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            if (a[j - 1] > a[j]) {
                t = a[j - 1];
                a[j - 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the `Random` class.

Comment: As @ZouZou said, use the `Random` class to generate 100 random values for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  The most important skill a developer (or anyone, really) can have, is an understanding of how to look things up on Google.  If you had typed "java random" into Google you would have gotten thousands of hits, with plenty of useful information on the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a random generator to get the numbers.
For an array of size X it would be something like this:

```
int[] array = new int[X];
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
    array[i] = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
```

You should take a look at the documentation for [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void generateRandom()
{
   int[] x = new int[100]; // This initializes an array of length 100
   Random rand = new Random();
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
       x[i] = rand.nextInt(100); // Use the random class to generate random integers (and give boundaries)
   }
}
```

Comment: @Dylan: This won't yield the specified range of `1-100`. Actually, `nextInt(int start, int end)` is not even a valid method of the `Random` class.

Comment: Oops indeed, it happens when mixing languages :P

Comment: Not quite there yet. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo what Jim has said in the comments. Being resourceful is an important skill as a software developer. A Google search would have quickly turned up a helpful article like [this one](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-to-generate-random-numbers).

You need to use the `Random` class to accomplish this.

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int array = new int[100];
for (int idx = 0; idx < 100; ++idx){
  array[idx] = randomGenerator.nextInt(100) + 1;
}
```

Note on the usage of the **nextInt(int n)** method:

It produces a pseudo-random integer between 0 (inclusive) and the specified integer (exclusive). That is the reason for adding `1` to the output of `nextInt(100)` as it shifts your output range from `0-99` to `1-100` as desired.